# invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::basic_ostream<char>' and 'ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>')) std::cout<<check<<std::cout;

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I'm trying to solve a standard interview question. I've a vector where each element is a vector itself of ints. V[0] is employee 0 and the vector of ints in v[0] is the number of employees reporting to him, say 2,3,5. Now if v[2] has 7 then indirectly 7 reports to employee 0 through 2. The question is to find a function that takes in two ints a and b and the vector of dependencies and say if a reports to b, directly or indirectly.

Here's the BFS logic

```
bool dependencyList(int a, int b, std::vector<std::vector<int>>& v){

    std::queue<int> Q;
    std::vector<int> D;
    std::unordered_map<int, int> M;

    for(auto it = v[b].begin(); it!= v[b].end(); it++){
        Q.push(*it);
        D.push_back(*it);
        M[*it] = 1;

    }
    while(!Q.empty()){
        int num = Q.front();
        for(auto it = v[num].begin(); it != v[num].end(); it++){
            if(M.find(*it) == M.end()){
                D.push_back(*it);
                M[*it] =1;
                Q.push(*it);
            }
        }
        Q.pop();
    }

    for(auto it= D.begin(); it!= D.end(); it++){
        if(*it == a) return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Here's the driver code

```
int main() {

    std::vector<int> v0;
    v0.push_back(2);
    v0.push_back(3);
    v0.push_back(7);

    std::vector<int> v1;
    v1.push_back(4);
    v1.push_back(9);
    v1.push_back(11);

    std::vector<int> v2;
    v2.push_back(3);
    v2.push_back(5);

    std::vector<int> v3;
    v3.push_back(8);
    v3.push_back(6);

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;
    v.push_back(v0);
    v.push_back(v1);
    v.push_back(v2);
    v.push_back(v3);

    bool check = dependencyList(6,0,v);

    std::cout<<check<<std::cout;

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the error that I get

```
invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::basic_ostream<char>' and 'ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>'))
    std::cout<<check<<std::cout;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^ ~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Read the line that's giving the error. Do you not see anything wrong with it?

Comment: Why do you need to `std::cout<<std::cout`  at all? Maybe you intended `std::cout << std::endl` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `std::cout;` from the expression `std::cout<<check<<std::cout;`If you compile this code using GNU g++ compiler, it compiles fine. But if you compile it using visual c++ compiler (c++11 this is what I tested with) it gives an error.

With g++ compiler  it displays the address of the object `std::cout`. So if you want to display the address, try `std::cout<<check<<&std::cout;`